# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. cur.fetchone() stops the while cicle

Tags: python, sql, nonetype

Ok, so here i'm basically trying to make a login option to my program, where it querys the database to see if the data is correct. It works fine until I introduce a login that's not in the database. Is there anyway I can make the while working even after the cur.fetchone() gives the error for not fecthing anything?

```
login= False    
print "*.*.*.*.*.*.*LOGIN*.*.*.*.*.*.*"
while login == False:
    login1=input("Id:")
    login1pw=raw_input("Password:")
    cur.execute("select id_func from func where (id_func = %s and function = 'admin');", (login1,))
    login2, = cur.fetchone()        
    cur.execute("select pw from func where id_func = %s", (login1,))
    login2pw, = cur.fetchone()
    if (login1 == login2 and login1pw == login2pw):
        login = True
        print "Login successful"
```

I get this error:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add:

```
r = cur.fetchone ()
if not r:
    print ('Login failed')
    continue
login2, = r
....
```

Same for the second fetch.

Comment: But now it doesnt test out if the password from the input is the same as the password from the database. It never actually runs this code:

if (login1 == login2 and login1pw == login2pw):
        login = True
        print "Login successful"

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to add a different variable and cur.fetchone. Sorry about that. It worked fine!